# Enable/Disable PNG crunching in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

How to Specifying PNG crunching in **BuildType** property.

How we can Enable/Disable PNG crunching in android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying PNG crunching is now a **BuildType** property and is disabled by default on debug builds:

```
android {
    …
    buildTypes {
        release {
            crunchPngs true// or false
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** It's available from [Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/06/android-studio-30-canary-5-is-now.html) .